# object is not iterable error in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am new to django rest framework, I am trying to build a simple movie API. I created 3 models Movie, Cast and Reviews, after applying migrations I added values in tables in django admin. When I start the server the api works fine until I again add values in Cast table or reviews table it gives me error like: "'Cast' object is not iterable". And its also not showing the Movie table data. What am I doing wrong.
Here is My code:

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.


class Cast(models.Model):
    actor = models.CharField(max_length=225)
    producer = models.CharField(max_length=225)
    director = models.CharField(max_length=225)
    screenwriter = models.CharField(max_length=225)


class Reviews(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=225)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=225)


class Movies(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=225)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=225)
    ratings = models.IntegerField()
    cast = models.ForeignKey(Cast, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    review = models.ForeignKey(Reviews, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

serializer.py

```
from .models import Movies, Reviews,Cast
from rest_framework import serializers


class CastSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Cast
        fields = ('actor', 'producer', 'director', 'screenwriter')


class ReviewsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Reviews
        fields = ('name', 'comment')


class MoviesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    cast = CastSerializer(many=True)
    review = ReviewsSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Movies
        fields = ('name', 'genre',  'ratings', 'cast' , 'review')
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from .serializers import MoviesSerializer, ReviewsSerializer, CastSerializer
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .models import Movies,  Reviews, Cast
# Create your views here


class MovieViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    def list(self, request):
        cast = Cast.objects.all()
        movies = Movies.objects.all()
        reviews = Reviews.objects.all()
        print(movies)
        movies_serializer = MoviesSerializer(movies, many=True)
        cast_serializer = CastSerializer(cast, many=True)
        reviews_serializer = ReviewsSerializer(reviews, many=True)
        data = {'movies_serializer': movies_serializer.data, 'cast_serializer': cast_serializer.data,
                'reviews_serializer': reviews_serializer.data}
        return Response(data)
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('movies/', include('api.urls'))
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here the `case` and `review` are in a FK relation with the `Movie` and hence your `MoviesSerializer` class must looks like

```
class MoviesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    cast = CastSerializer() # remove `many=True`
    review = ReviewsSerializer() # remove `many=True`

    class Meta:
        model = Movies
        fields = ('name', 'genre',  'ratings', 'cast' , 'review')
```

Comment: Thanks, it resolve the error, can you kindly explain why Many=true was giving error?

Comment: When you put `many=True` DRF expect the data to be iterable. In your case, **`Movies.cast`** is not an iterable.\